# Integral of a differential form on a torus

Tags: integration, differential-topology, differential-forms, pullback

Can someone check if my work here is on the right track:

> Compute $$\int_{S^{1} \times S^{1}} f^{*} \mathbb{\omega}$$ where $f\colon S^{1} \times S^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ is a smooth map and $\mathbb{\omega} =  dx_{1} \wedge dx_{2} - dx_{3}\wedge dx_{4}$ is a two-form on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ in the standard coordinates.

Here is what I have done so far. Let, $f(u,v) \rightarrow(x_{1}(u,v), x_{2}(u,v), x_{3}(u,v), x_{4}(u,v))$. So $$dx_{1} = \frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial u} du + \frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial v} dv$$ and we can do the same for $dx_2, dx_3$ and $dx_4$. So I get:

$$\int_{S^{1} \times S^{1}} \left(\frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial u}\right) du \wedge dv + \left(\frac{\partial x_{4}}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x_{4}}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial x_{3}}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x_{3}}{\partial v}\right) du \wedge dv, $$

but I am not sure where to go from here. Any tips?

Comment: I have not tried to write anything down, but I would be more careful using coordinates on $S^1 \times S^1$, as you do not have a global chart. You may use the fact that $S^1$ has two local charts. You can then translate the computation to $\mathbb R^2$. Since $d\omega = 0$ and $d(f^*\omega) = f^*d\omega = 0$, the form $f^*\omega$ is closed, thus is exact on each patch. Perhaps you can try this way and see what you find.

Comment: @Gibbs Normally, I'd also be worried about not having a global chat, but for the specific case of $S^1 \times S^1$, we have a chart which covers "most" (i.e except a set of Lebesgue measure zero) of the manifold, so I believe for the purposes of integration it doesn't matter. The (inverse of the chart) map being $(\alpha, \beta) \mapsto (e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\beta})$ from $(0,2\pi) \times (0,2\pi) \to S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: Are you sure that your final expression is correct?

Comment: I don’t think that the expressions are correct. Anyway, even with the correct expression I am not sure if one can make any progress because $f$ is not known. So I would rather observe that $S^1\times S^1$ is compact and therefore $f$ Must be proper. Since $\mathbb{R}^4$ Is non-compact, f can not be surjective. The degree of $f$ therefore must be zero. And, we can then conclude that $\int f^*\omega=0.$

Comment: @peek-a-boo may be you are right, I should write something down to convince myself. In any case, I think with the steps I was suggesting one can then use Stokes' theorem and conclude the integral is zero, which fits with the result of WhoKnowsWho - although I am not sure what the degree of $f$ should be.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho: The degree of $f$ is not even defined, so your degree statement is wrong. (And double-check how you actually would compute degree with forms, anyhow.) However, you're correct that the OP miscomputed the pullback. Let me also comment that any $2$-form on $S^1\times S^1$ is closed; what's more interesting is that $f^*\omega$ is *exact*. What is the integral of an exact $2$-form over a compact surface (with no boundary)?

Comment: Okay, I see that $\omega$ is already closed in $\R^4.$  I did not look at $\omega,$ my mistake. You are right, one can directly observe that $f^*\omega$ is exact. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I realised why degree is not defined. Thanks for pointing that out.